Is using a different subnet on a downstream router enough to isolate a network client?
Say I have a network host that's potentially infected with malware capable of reaching out to fellow network hosts (possibly able to crack SMB passwords) and replicate itself to other hosts.
Is this network configuration sufficient to prevent it from penetrating the private network?

Edit & Clarifications
These are both basic consumer/soho routers.  Before applying the static route, hosts on 192.168.0.0/24 can access resources on 192.168.1.0/24.  After applying the static route, they cannot.

are these home/soho internet access routers? generally with consumer-grade routers, this won't help isolate the affected host unless you configure the firewall to prevent the isolated host(s) from sending traffic across the WAN on the internal router. by default, the infected host would be able to reach all the private network hosts. you would be better off swapping the two routers, so that the infected host is upstream rather than downstream. right now your infected host can reach the outer lan, but hosts in the outer lan cannot reach the infected host.

@FrankThomas: I should clarify, the infected host would still require Internet access, but I want to block from any LAN hosts on the private router.  Will the static route on the downstream router not block access to the private router's subnet?  I applied this as a test and I was unable to ping or access any hosts on the private subnet from a host on the downstream router.

so, first off. once again I'm assuming we're talking about a consumer grade router. a router of this kind does not need you to create a route between its LAN and WAN networks. passing traffic between them is literally the only job it has. the route you specified however is for the whole /24 network, so it provides a route to the enter .1.0/24 network (which once again, the router doesn't need). many factors may affect your ping results, but if you are getting internet on that system, then it has access to the .1.0/24 network, cause thats where the internet comes in from.

There may be more to your configuration that impacts your outcomes, but as you have described the situation, you are not meaningfully isolating the Infected system from systems in 192.168.1.0/24. it can reach them. they can't reach it, unless they are replying to a connection it created, but nothing about the configuration your diagram expresses would limit the infected machine from connecting to services on the outter LAN.

why don't you show us the route table on the affected machine.
